# Ada get Character input and check if it is a valid input

Tags: character, ada

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Characters.Handling;
with Ada.Exceptions; use Ada.Exceptions;
USE Ada, Ada.Text_Io;

WITH connectfour;
PROCEDURE Main IS
   PACKAGE board is new connectfour;
   USE board;
   col : Character;

   function checkInput (input : Character) RETURN BOOLEAN is
      ins : Character := input;
   begin
      ins := Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Lower(ins);
      if ins = 'a' or ins = 'b' or ins = 'c' or ins = 'd' or
         ins = 'e' or ins = 'f' or ins = 'g' or ins = 'h' then
         return true;
      end if;
      return false;
    end checkInput;

begin
    board.initialize;
    board.print;

    while (not board.isFull) loop
        loop
            PUT("Player"&Integer'Image(board.turn)&": ");
            Ada.Text_IO.Get(col);
            exit when checkInput(col);
        end loop;

        exit when col = '0';
        Text_IO.New_Line;
        Text_IO.Put ("");
        board.play(col);
    end loop;
end Main;
```

So when I run my program I get:

Player 1: a  --> (I entered the character 'a' and clicked enter)

Then I keep getting this error right after, at the line "Ada.Text_IO.Get(col);"

**raised ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR : a-tiinio.adb:86 instantiated at a-inteio.ads:18**

What I want to do, is get a single character input from the user and check if it is within the range A .. H, if yes, then exit the loop, otherwise keep asking...

I cannot find out what my issue is...

I allow the user to enter lowercase or uppercase characters, and I convert uppercase to lowercase and perform a check.

Please help...

I am not sure how to read in a single Character....

Comment: Please add the `with` and `use` clauses to the code snippet, they may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: @Brian Drummond Ok I added the with and use clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the exception message could be clearer (and there are ways to get stack traces when one happens but let's work with what we've got...)

```
locate a-tiinio.adb
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/rts-native/adainclude/a-tiinio.adb
```

which is

```
package body Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO
```

and line 86 is an exception raised in

```
procedure Get
     (Item  : out Num;
      Width : Field := 0)
```

Details don't matter (yet) but I cannot see any calls to Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO.Get.

So my suspicion is that the code shown is working 
(as well as can be expected : NOTE HOWEVER there is no way to get to `exit when col = '0';` with `col` outside a .. h) and there is another call to Get (this time Integer_IO.Get) buried in `board.play`. It would be easy to test this by printing col=  before calling board.play.

Minor style comment:

```
   function checkInput (input : Character) RETURN BOOLEAN is
      ins : Character := input;
   begin
      ins := Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Lower(ins);
```

can be simplified

```
   function checkInput (input : Character) RETURN BOOLEAN is
      ins : Character := Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Lower(input);
   begin
```

Comment: Ok, you solved my problem haha. Yea so... it stupid though... because I had with Ada.Integer_Text_IO in my clauses it did that... now I removed that with clause and it works fine... so stupid...

Comment: Simply removing a supposedly unused "with" clause shouldn't have resolved the problem; was there something else going on? (in board.play)?

Comment: Nope, that is all I changed and it worked... interesting huh.